# Probability the stock price (following geometric Brownian motion) hits the upper boundary U before there is a retracement from the max by amount R?

Tags: probability, geometric-brownian, stopping-time

I am looking for the probability that the stock price/Geometric Brownian Motion hits the upper boundary U, before there is a retracement (from the maximum price) that exceeds amount R.  In other words, for my application the lower bound isn't a constant boundary at L, it is a fixed distance R that is measured from the maximum price.

Thank you for considering this problem!

Comment: Just one observation : L must vary between $S_0 - R$ and $U-R$ so you can bound the probability accordingly using the known formulae for fixed U and L

Comment: @dm63 Thank you for your suggestion.  A lower bound on the probability I am looking for would help a lot. Unfortunately the bound in the suggestion above is an upper bound...

Comment: @dm63 I am interested in finding the probability stock price reaches objective U before a "trailing stop-loss" is triggered by the price retracing a fixed amount R from its current maximum. If the maximum price is achieved at time t*, then the probability I am looking for is the probability that the stopping time of the maximum being above U is smaller than the stopping time of the minimum (defined on time interval t* ≤ s ≤ t being above maximum - R.

Comment: @dm63 Let t* be the earliest time at which Bs has attained its maximum thus far: t* ≡ min{s ∈ [0, t]|Bs = max{Br |r ∈ [0, t]}}. Thus Bt* is the maximum attained by time t. Let t** be the latest time at which the distance between Bt* and the minimum on time interval (t*, t) does not exceed amount R. t** ≡ max{t ∈ [0, T ]| Bt* - min{Bq |q ∈ [t*, t]} < R} }. Let t***≡ min{s ∈ [0, t]|Bt* > U}. I am looking for the P(t*** < t**).

Comment: Yes I understand what you are searching for and I do not know how to calculate that exactly- but I did provide a 2 sided bound in my comment , not a one sided.

Comment: I was talking about the interval the probability (that can't be computed precisely) is in, and not about the interval the Brownian Motion is in.  In any case, thank you for your posts!